# How to use regexp-me library?

Tags: regex, blackberry, java-me

I am pretty surprised that when I come across J2ME does not have the normal regex that I have been using in the J2SE.

I found this J2ME supported regex library: [regexp-me](http://regexp-me.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/regexp-me/doc/index.html)

Anyone can tell me how to get the starting/ending position or something like matcher.group() (in J2SE), from this library. I can see that it has a boolean return function 'match', but that is not what I want.

Moreover, they use curly bracket with the getParenStart(0) to retrieve the matched regex, but I never use such thing before in J2SE, can't really understand what is it doing.

For example:

```
regex = a.+b
```

The string that I want to search in:

```
kkkkacccb789
```

I want to know the position of  `acccb` or preferably get the whole matched string,  `acccb` out of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've already figured it out.  This snippet will do the match you want, and put the matching part of the string in the local variable `matchedSubstring`

```
RE regex = new RE("a.+b");
r.match("kkkkacccb789");
String matchedSubstring = r.getParen(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, just tested, it works, I thought we don't need to call regex.match before regex.getParen (I thought regex.getParent already call regex.match internally), that was why my code didn't work.

Comment: But can it matches more than one occurances? It seem like doesn't work that way.